# Blinking LED using Arrays and Pointer Arithmetic

Tags: c, pointers, arm, pointer-arithmetic

```
#include "lm4f120h5qr.h"
#define LED_RED (1u<<1)
#define LED_BLUE (1u<<2)
#define LED_GREEN (1u<<3)

    GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R  |= LED_RED; // line1

    *((unsigned long volatile *)(0x40025000 +(LED_RED << 2)))=LED_RED;//line2
    *(GPIO_PORTF_DATA_BITS_R + LED_RED)=LED_RED; //line3
    GPIO_PORTF_DATA_BITS_R[LED_RED]=LED_RED;  //line3
```

I am following a course on internet, and this is an example of using "Arrays and Pointer Arithmetic".
But i couldn't understand the concept of using "pointer arithmetic" to modify specific bit.

I can understand "line1", which modifies a bit, without changing any other bits in location where GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R points to, so it turns on the RED LED (please correct me if i get it wrong here).

I can understand why we shift 2 bits in "line2", cause we ignore 2 last bits, and "line2" and "line3" share the same concept, they did the same instruction in Disassembly.

My 1st question is where *(GPIO_PORTF_DATA_BITS_R + LED_RED) exactly points to? and how *(GPIO_PORTF_DATA_BITS_R + LED_RED) = LED_RED works?

2nd problem is why we don't need shift 2 bits anymore in "line3". They said that it did it automatically but can someone explain the reason behind?

Thank you.

Comment: For any pointer or array `p` and index `i`, the expression `*(p + i)` is exactly equal to `p[i]`. And on most systems a pointer is simply an integer whose value is a memory address.

Comment: Where is `GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R` defined? We need to know its type.

Comment: Sorry, this seems like a terrible course. Way to confuse your students. Line 1 seems to modify the pointer, not the address pointed to.

Comment: @CrisLuengo it was just my terrible English and the way i explain it, BTW i found the answer. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the context is, but I can answer your two questions:

1. If `GPIO_PORTF_DATA_BITS_R` is meant to be an array, `*(GPIO_PORTF_DATA_BITS_R + LED_RED)=LED_RED` is assigning the unsigned int value `LED_RED` to the `LED_RED`th position in the array. Again not sure why you want to assign `LED_RED` to that position in the array, but that's up to you.
2. Shifting a value left 2 bits is multiplying it by 4. You need to do this in line 2 because `GPIO_PORTF_DATA_BITS_R` is an array of 4-byte values (I Googled and saw it was 32-bit). Memory is byte-addressed, so if you want to go to the `LED_RED`th position in the array, you add `LED_RED * 4` to the memory address of the start of the array. However, pointer arithmetic in C is aware of the size of `*GPIO_PORTF_DATA_BITS_R` and therefore automatically does the times 4 multiplication in line 3.

Edit: Instead of shifting `LED_RED` 2 bytes to the left, a cleaner way to calculate a memory address offset is `LED_RED * sizeof(*GPIO_PORTF_DATA_BITS_R)` (or do what you did in line 3 if you're just setting an array value).

Comment: it was GPIO_PORTF_DATA_BITS_R, not GPIO_PORTF_DATA_DATA_R, sorry, i edited

Comment: Ah, I was wondering why you were doing the `|=` on it in line 1. Ok.